# Writing kernel functions using PyOpenCL with AVX2 or AVX512?

Tags: python, opencl

Am I restricted to using AVX2 or AVX512 depending on what family type my CPU is (if it is AVX2 or AVX512)?

I am writing an openCL program in Python using the PyOpenCL package, and I want to optimize the AVX2 SIMD technology. I know AVX2 is 256-bit instruction and AVX512 is 512-bit, so when I write my kernel function should I only use double4 variables in order to implement AVX2-style instruction? And vice-versa, double8 variables for AVX-512 style?

And my next question is: Am I restricted to what my CPU type supports? If it supports AVX-256, will I not be able to run double8 variables parallelization in my kernel function?

Sorry if my question is confusing because I am still in the process of learning this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes more sense to answer your questions in reverse order:

> Am I restricted to what my CPU type supports? If it supports AVX-256, will I not be able to run double8 variables parallelization in my kernel function?

No, all OpenCL implementations which support `double` floating point types also allow you to write code using `double8` types. What that gets compiled down to is entirely up to the implementation though.

If your CPU supports AVX-512, and your OpenCL implementation does too, there's a good chance it'll attempt to emit AVX-512 instructions. If CPU or implementation only support AVX2, it will internally probably attempt to break down your code into operating on each half of your `double8` individually.

> when I write my kernel function should I only use double4 variables in order to implement AVX2-style instruction? And vice-versa, double8 variables for AVX-512 style?

Your first reference for this sort of question should always be the OpenCL optimisation manual for your specific OpenCL implementation. For Intel's CPU runtime, [this seems to be the relevant resource](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iocl-opg-coding-for-the-intel-cpu-opencl-device).

Depending on what your code does, the OpenCL implementation may be able to autovectorise your code even if your kernel uses scalar types, operating on arrays of `double`s, assuming you've submitted a suitable number of work items.

If your code is naturally representable by vector types such as `double8` and `double4`, go ahead and use them. The implementation will be able to split code using `double8` into instructions using `double4` internally as I've mentioned. You may find that this causes more register pressure, so using larger than necessary types can be slightly counterproductive. If you only want to write one variant of the code, go for the bigger vectors though - *again, if the code can naturally be represented that way*. If you have to go through contortions to make it fit, chances are you won't gain much.

If care about a few percent performance difference, you'll need to perform detailed profiling and try lots of different approaches anyway. It always heavily depends on your specific code, so it's very difficult to give general advice.